# Navigate from current action to an action of another controller and display the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this, an action of Product Controller :

```
public ActionResult SortedLists(List<string> items, string ShopID)
{
    //Do sth...

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControlPanel", new {ID = ShopID });
}
```

And Index is the action(view) of ControlPanel Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(int ID)
{
     ViewBag.theRelatedShopID = ID;     
     return View();
}
```

I traced the code. the Index page rendered but nothing displayed in browser. just a '#' added to URL like this : `http://localhost:55161/#` . why I can't see the page?

The page Index is not strongly-typed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try passing the value via TempData. TempData is much like ViewData but is used to pass values across requests

For example, try

```
TempData["ID"] = ShopID;
```

!!**Just a word of caution**, using TempData in your controller actions, will making unit testing harder